# Adding to and creating a List Manager list programatically

Tags: list-manager

Does anyone have examples on, how to create list, add items to List Manager programatically?

Comment: how to get list by name, if not there then add it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 types of lists: Contact List and segmented list, each one has its own class to handle them.

You need a reference to: Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.dll

### Contact List

```
//Get the manager
var listManager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("contactListManager", false) as ContactListManager;

//Create a list
ContactList list =  new ContactList()
{
    Name = name,
    Description = description,
    ParentId = new ID(parentId)
};
listManager.Create(list);

//Move the list to a folder (its parent)
listManager.MoveList(list.Id, list.ParentId.ToString());

//Finding a list by ID.
var list = listManager.FindById(listId);
```

### Segmented List Manager

```
var segmentedListManager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("segmentedListManager", false) as SegmentedListManager;
```

All the other methods are the same.

These are the most basic operations you can do with lists, let me know if you need to do something else.

Comment: Which dll has this class ContactList?

Comment: I have updated the answer: Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.dll

Comment: In later versions it's Sitecore.ListManagement.dll