# Can we import data from Eloqua or Marketo into Sitecore xDB?

Tags: xdb

We need to import contacts details in `xDB` from the marketing tools like `Eloqua or Marketo`. Does Sitecore provide any tool to do so in `Sitecore v8.1`?

Comment: No, Sitecore doesn't proved tool for it. You will need to create it by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no OOTB functionality.

You need to create it by your own.

I would create console app to do it for you.

You basically need to follow these 3 steps:

1. Export Data from Eloqua/Marketo - You can use REST API that Eloqua / Marketo provide -> https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/getLeadsByFilterUsingGET or https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/rest-endpoints.html; You are not mentioning it in your question but you need to get contacts/leads together with their membership / contact list "assignments"
2. Create contact lists that mimic Marketo / Eloqua once in Sitecore by using Sitecore API with data from first step. Follow this thread -> [Adding to and creating a List Manager list programatically](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/adding-to-and-creating-a-list-manager-list-programatically)
3. Create contacts by using Sitecore API with data from first step and assign them to proper contact lists. Follow this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634909/sitecore-8-1-exm-3-2-how-to-add-contact-to-a-list-in-list-manager-programatical

Comment: Thanks for providing response. I will try to implement it and will provide you feedback.